# Default p-value obtained in R

Tags: r, chi-squared, hypothesis-test

In R when I use the *chisq.test()* function, what is the p-value that is computed? Is it two sided, upper tail or lower tail ?

Thanks in advance for helping out this beginner

Comment: What should be a onesided alternative hypothesis H1 for the chi²-test?

Answer (score 2):

P-values for  `χ2` test are always one-sided, due to how results are interpreted. `χ2` tests test goodness of fit, which means that the result has only one favorable outcome, so the p-value is probability that the fit is good. This is more of a statistics question than a coding question, and is probably better suited for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).